# What does @. do in Julia?

Tags: macros, julia

I am trying to use the [LsqFit package](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/LsqFit.jl) in Julia, and the documentation makes use of a macro `@.` without really explaining how it works.  It is not clear to me from the package documentation whether this is a standard Julia macro or something peculiar to the package, and I can't find a reference to this macro elsewhere.  How does `@.` work in Julia?

Comment: [`@.` macro](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.Broadcast.@__dot__), 
[manual entry](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1) and [complement](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#More-dots:-Fuse-vectorized-operations-1)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check documentation for any Julia function by pressing `?` to go to the help mode, see the output below:

```
help?> @.
  @. expr

  Convert every function call or operator in expr into a "dot call" (e.g. convert f(x) to f.(x)), and convert
  every assignment in expr to a "dot assignment" (e.g. convert += to .+=).

  If you want to avoid adding dots for selected function calls in expr, splice those function calls in with $.
  For example, @. sqrt(abs($sort(x))) is equivalent to sqrt.(abs.(sort(x))) (no dot for sort).
```

Describing the documentation above in other words the `@.` allows you to vectorize all function calls in the expression following a macro.

If you are unsure how any Julia macro works I recommend using the `@macroexpand` macro, for example:

```
julia> @macroexpand @. [1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]
:((+).([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid dot assignment while using @.? e.g. @. a = b*c

Comment: Normally, there is no need to vectorize an assignment. If there is a vector on right hand side it will be assigned to the left side.One exception could be something like `A = zeros(4, 4); B = [1, 2, 3, 4]; A .= B`, type `?.=` for more info.

Comment: Right, the problem is if I just write @. a = b*c, I have to declare 'a' first, otherwise I get varundefError. On the other hand, if we can avoid .= while using @., I don't need to do that.

Comment: Perhaps you mean  `a = @. b*c`  in that case a does not need to be declared